# exclude a property from sequelize create method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table called
`users`
has these columns

```
id
email
password
```

when I create a new user using `const user = await User.create({email,password})`

I got the created user stored in `user`

the key here is I don't want to have the `password` property in the `user` constant above

how to exclude a property from sequelize or using javascript logic..

Comment: Why would you have a model with some fields and not want these fields ? Shouldn't you reconsider the way you wrote your model instead ?

Comment: Two ways here: 1. you don't want to get/update `password` field at all using Sequelize  - you need to exclude this field from Sequelize model and make it optional in DB 2. you don't want to set it while creating a record only - you need to construct a new object without `password` prop and pass it to `create`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a user with password but do not want that to be returned by `create` function and stored in local `user` variable?

Comment: Yes because i am returning it to the backend